# Google Apps script returning every date minus one day

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I assume it has something to do with timezone, but I cannot figure out how to add a day. I would like to only display the month. The issue is at the bottom of the code:

```
function compull() {
  var linkssheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1hxkrSKhoUyveyK7dLr-xPpYxhZVvlKJt3S5L6rpMS7w").getSheetByName("Links");
  var comsource = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1egqeIX6Lf2As2tsT0U8yhV41fg7as3dOLnwGryU9GVs"); 
  var adjustmentssource = comsource.getSheetByName("Adjustments").getRange("A:I").getValues().filter(function(item){ return item[0] != ""; });
  var compullsource = comsource.getSheetByName("Calculator").getRange("A:Q").getValues().filter(function(item){ return item[0] != ""; });
    
  
  //var length = 4;
  var length = 1 + getLastRowSpecial(linkssheet.getRange("E:E").getValues());

  
  var comlength = 1 + getLastRowSpecial(compullsource);
  var adjlength = 1 + getLastRowSpecial(adjustmentssource);
 
  for (i=2; i<length; i++) {
    var writelocation = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(linkssheet.getRange(i,5).getValue());
    var compull = writelocation.getSheetByName("Commissions");
    var id = linkssheet.getRange(i,1).getDisplayValue();
    var id2 = linkssheet.getRange(i,2).getDisplayValue();
        
    
    var rowlength = comlength;
    var columnlength = compullsource[0].length;        
    dataarray = [];            
    dataarray.push(compullsource[0].slice());    
    for (j=1;j<compullsource.length;j++){
      if(compullsource[j][1] == id){
        dataarray.push(compullsource[j].slice());                       
      }        
    }    
    for (k=0;k<dataarray.length;k++){
     dataarray[k].splice(1,2);       
    }     
   compull.getRange(4,1,dataarray.length,dataarray[0].length).clearContent();
   compull.getRange(4,1,dataarray.length,dataarray[0].length).setValues(dataarray);
    
    
    
    var rowlength = adjlength;
    var columnlength = adjustmentssource[0].length;
    dataarray2 = [];
    dataarray2.push(adjustmentssource[0].slice());
    for (j=1;j<adjustmentssource.length;j++){
      if(adjustmentssource[j][1] == id2){
        dataarray2.push(adjustmentssource[j].slice());       
      }        
    }
    for (k=0;k<dataarray2.length;k++){
    dataarray2[k].splice(0,2); 
    }
    
    
    compull.getRange(4,17,dataarray2.length,dataarray2[0].length).clearContent();
    compull.getRange(4,17,dataarray2.length,dataarray2[0].length).setValues(dataarray2);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();

    //change date in adjustments in Column Q
    
    var date = compull.getRange("Q5:Q")
    var values = date.getValues();
    values[0][0] = Utilities.formatDate(date, "GMT-8:00", "MM");
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [so]. I have poste an answer. If you required some more specific add a [mcve] and a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You should know that the spreadsheet settings and the script project have their own timezone, so if you have problems with dates one of the first things that you should check is that each of them is using the correct timezone.

This part of the code is wrong

```
var date = compull.getRange("Q5:Q")
var values = date.getValues();
values[0][0] = Utilities.formatDate(date, "GMT-8:00", "MM");
```

The problem is that the first argument of `formatDate` should be a `Date` object but `date` had assigned a `Range` object.

Resources

- [Working with Dates and Times](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/features/dates)